# Watch triggers only once - vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Vue3 newbie here. I am trying to toggle a string value, but watch triggers only once.

```
<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <table>
      <thead>
       ...
          <th>
            <div className="create-date-label">
              <p>Create Date</p>
              <i
                @click="toggleSortDate"
                :className="
                  sortDirection === SORT_DIRECTIONS.DESCENDING
                    ? 'fa fa-arrow-down'
                    : 'fa fa-arrow-up'
                "
              />
            </div>
          </th>
        ...
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar.vue";
import ConfigurationRow from "../components/ConfigurationRow.vue";
const SORT_DIRECTIONS = Object.freeze({
  ASCENDING: "ASCENDING",
  DESCENDING: "DESCENDING",
});

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    Navbar,
    ConfigurationRow,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      configurations: [],
      SORT_DIRECTIONS,
      sortDirection: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleSortDate() {
      if (this.sortDirection === this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.ASCENDING)
        this.sortDirection = this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.DESCENDING;
      if (this.sortDirection === this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.DESCENDING)
        this.sortDirection = this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.ASCENDING;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    sortDirection: function (newDirection) {
      console.log("watch sort direction", newDirection); //Prints ASCENDING once
      if (newDirection === this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.ASCENDING)
        this.configurations = this.configurations.sort(
          (a, b) => a.date.getTime() - b.date.getTime()
        );
      else if (newDirection === this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.DESCENDING)
        this.configurations = this.configurations.sort(
          (a, b) => b.date.getTime() - a.date.getTime()
        );
    },
    deep: true, //Tried with removing this too, same result
  },
  created() {
    this.configurations = [
      {
        key: "some_key",
        value: "1.4.5.21",
        description: "This is a kind of a long description",
        date: new Date(),
      },
      {
        key: "another_key",
        value: "1.2",
        description: "Desc",
        date: new Date(),
      },
      {
        key: "min_value",
        value: "13",
        description:
          "This is a kind of a long description This is a kind of a long description This is a kind of a long description ",
        date: new Date(),
      },
    ].sort((a, b) => a.date.getTime() - b.date.getTime());
    this.sortDirection = this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.DESCENDING;
  },
};
</script>
```

I am using `vue3` but do I *have to* use `ref` or `reactive` to achieve this? Anybody have an idea on how this triggers once but not again?

Comment: There are some few things to talk about. First of you should write your `sort()` as a `method` (in methods) or a `computed property`. Be aware what the vue-lifecyle are. You don't need ref or reactive -> this is only important if you write your script with the `composition API`. Another hint: you don't need a watcher at all. After you click your method the sort() will be triggered anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but why do I need the `sort` function as a method? And I just want to change the sortDirection with the toggle function, how would the array sort without a watcher? I will try using the computed property. How can I trigger `computed` based on `sortDirection` value change tho?

Comment: There are many things going up there. My main suggestion is writing your component in vue-style. So you should keep a look at the [vue style guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/style-guide/). If you seperate your methods it will help you to maintain your project. For other aspects you should try to write a computed property for yourself or ask specific questions. I can't answer them all in one comment. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
toggleSortDate() {
  if (this.sortDirection === this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.ASCENDING)
    this.sortDirection = this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.DESCENDING;
  else if (this.sortDirection === this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.DESCENDING)
    this.sortDirection = this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.ASCENDING;
},
```

Comment: How is this different?

Comment: You statement is simply wrong.
if (this.sortDirection === this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.ASCENDING)
you make it to: this.sortDirection = this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.DESCENDING;
than you ask:
if (this.sortDirection === this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.DESCENDING)
and put it :
this.sortDirection = this.SORT_DIRECTIONS.ASCENDING;

So your watcher does not trigger at all, if you change it to else it will work.

Comment: Oh my lord, my brain was auto-completing that `else`. Thanks a lot! :D